# Why can't Django installed with pip be imported by Python, whereas Django installed with apt-get works fine?

Tags: apt, package-management, python, pip

I prefer generally to use `pip` rather than `apt-get` for installing python modules, as I prefer to separate the packages for Python development from general system packages. However, it seems as though `pip` won't work for me. I want to install Django, and when I used `sudo pip install Django`, the installation went through successfully. However, when I opened my Python interpreter REPL, I could not successfully `import django` - I received an `ImportError` that `Django` could not be found. On the other hand, upon running `sudo apt install python-django`, the installation was successful again, and this time, I could import Django.

So why does this happen? With the `pip` installation, for some reason, Django was not in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`, which is where modules installed with pip go, but `django-admin` was installed and usable, proving that `pip` must have installed Django. On the other hand, after installing Django with `apt`/`apt-get`, Django folders were existing in `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`, where any modules I install with the system package manager are found. I don't know what else I can do to troubleshoot this issue - please tell me if there is anything I am missing and should add.

EDIT
I also tried `easy_install`, which installed to my Python 3.5, and then `pip3`, and both allowed importing from the Python 3 interpreter. So why doesn't `pip` for Python 2.7 work in installing Django? I tried another module with `pip` for 2.7, and everything worked fine. This is just with Django.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that my `pip` was, for some reason, pointing to Python 3.5, even though there was already `pip3` for that. I fixed it.